# Hard Coded number(s) found

Tags: c, if-statement

i just got my grades for a homework i had to and it's tell me : ‎⁨
Hard coded number(s) found in hw2q1.c:

```
else if (number_letter < 6 && condition_r == 0) {
else if ((sum_value % 5) != 0 || number_letter > 4) {
    if (number_letter < 6 && condition_r == 0) {
```

Reduced 10 points for hard coded number(s) usage. I dont fully understand the " hard coded " definition and why it's wrong how i wrote my if.

Thank you ;)
PS : My code works fine and its pass all the test with success

Comment: I think we're lacking enough context to know why hard coded numbers are bad in this instance

Comment: Could be related to the use of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))? It's not always bad though, especially if you have good documentation (comments) about it.

Comment: You can find many results if you look for the term 'magic numbers' in the context of programming. There will also be a healthy dose of what your professor considers bad use vs. what is significant to developing it.

Answer (score 3):

Hard coded numbers are integer literals. They are also known as [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).
In your code, they are `6, 0, 5, 4`.

Those who read your code will not understand what they stand for. And after a few weeks you may not remember either.

So better give names to these numbers. Something like:

```
const int number_letter_max = 6; 
const int number_letter_min = 4;
const int condition_r_check = 0;
const int sum_value_divisible = 5;
```

Then your code becomes:

```
else if (number_letter < number_letter_max  && condition_r == condition_r_check) {
else if ((sum_value % sum_value_divisible ) != 0 || number_letter > number_letter_min ) {
    if (number_letter < condition_r_check  && condition_r == condition_r_check)
```

Comment: It is at least to some extent down to personal preference, but I find the original version — with hard-coded numbers — much clearer (in this particular case; I am not arguing this in general).

Comment: @NPE: Yes, if we have more context, it might show that hard-coded numbers are better. After all, we don't need variables for the number of days in a week, months in a year etc.

Comment: One question to ask yourself is: could this value __ever__ change? If it could, then there is a _strong_ argument for replacing the number with a named constant. Another related consideration is: does the same value appear more than once in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Hard coded constants is constants without a name, or to be more precise, literals. There are two drawbacks with these:

- It is hard to understand why the constant has that specific value.
- They often occur more than once, so changing the value requires changing it everywhere. This takes more work and is risky.

To fix this you should replace these constants with a define, so instead of having this code:

```
else if (number_letter < 6 && condition_r == 0) {
else if ((sum_value % 5) != 0 || number_letter > 4) {
if (number_letter < 6 && condition_r == 0) {
```

You should write something like this:

```
#define    CONDITION_FALSE           0
#define    NUMBER_LETTER_MIN         6
#define    SUM_VALUE_DEVIDE_FACTOR   0

else if (number_letter < NUMBER_LETTER_MIN && condition_r == CONDITION_FALSE) {
else if ((sum_value % SUM_VALUE_DEVIDE_FACTOR) != CONDITION_FALSE || number_letter > NUMBER_LETTER_MIN - 1) {
    if (number_letter < NUMBER_LETTER_MIN && condition_r == CONDITION_FALSE) {
```

Obviously you should replace these defines with more accurate descriptions that make sense with the context.